# Expresso Store Fatal error trying to install

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, white-screen-of-death

I'm getting a fatal error installing Store 2.4.1 on a fresh install of ee2.9.2

Anyone have any ideas the cause / solution?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unknown CI database driver 'mysqli'' in

/home/eedemo1/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db/src/CodeIgniterConnection.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /home//eedemo1/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(160): Illuminate\CodeIgniter\CodeIgniterConnection->getDefaultQueryGrammar() 
#1 /home/eedemo1/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db/src/CodeIgniterConnection.php(22): Illuminate\Database\Connection->useDefaultQueryGrammar() 
#2 /home/eedemo1/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db/src/CodeIgniterConnectionResolver.php(24): Illuminate\CodeIgniter\CodeIgniterConnection->__construct(Object(Addons)) 
#3 /home/eedemo1/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Container.php(30): Illuminate\CodeIgniter\CodeIgniterConnection in /home/eedemo1/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db/src/CodeIgniterConnection.php on line 39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store relies on a library called `expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db`. The latest version of this library *does* support `mysqli`, but the version that comes packaged with Store is older and does not contain `mysqli` support.

Replace your `system/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db` folder with the latest version found here: https://github.com/expressodev/laravel-codeigniter-db

Answer (score 2):

The quick fix I found was just to change the dbdriver to 'mysql' not mysqli in the database config, however this is not so much a fix as a work around.

Comment: Did you ever hear anything else on this from devdemon?

Comment: Same. Had to change ee database.php from:<br>
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';<br>
to<br>
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';<br> This is a concern as it touches everything.

Comment: @Vtomic Sorry I should have stated that I was able to change it back to mysql after install and it worked as expected.